# descret math handshaking problem

Tags: discrete-mathematics

There are some men and 15 women in a row. Each man shake hand with exactly 6 women and each woman shake hand with exactly 8 men. How many men are in the room?

Comment: Can you tell us a little about what you've tried so far?

Answer (score 2):

That each woman shakes hands with exactly 8 men implies that there are a total of $8 \cdot 15 = 120$ handshakes. Can you see how to continue the reasoning from there?

Answer (score 0):

The total of shakehands must be the same. Because the amount of shakehands every woman does is $8/6$ times higher than the handshakes that the men do, the quantity of men hast to be $8/6$ times higher than the quantity of women.

Thus:  **#men = $8/6 \cdot$ #women = $8/6\cdot 15$ = 20**